# Table data show one by one record different two tables?

Tags: sql

Table 1

| ABC | DEF |
| --- | --- |
| GS | PM |
| BS | PK |

Table 2

| ABC | DEF |
| --- | --- |
| YZ | TT |
| UG | KK |

Need output

| ABC | DEF |
| --- | --- |
| GS | PM |
| YZ | TT |
| BS | PK |
| UG | KK |

So please help me sql query

Comment: You are looking for `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table1:

| Azbuka | Def |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 |
| A2 | D2 |
| A3 | D3 |
| A4 | D4 |

table2:

| Azbuka | Def |
| --- | --- |
| F1 | H1 |
| F2 | H2 |
| F3 | H3 |
| F4 | H4 |

```
DECLARE @max INT

select @max = count(*) from table1

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE num<@max
)
SELECT t1.* FROM CTE CC
inner join 
(
    Select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS RNum, 
        Azbuka, 
        Def 
    from table1
    union all 
    Select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS RNum, 
        Azbuka, 
        Def 
    from table2
) t1 on t1.RNum = CC.num
```

Result:

| Azbuka | Def |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 |
| F1 | H1 |
| A2 | D2 |
| F2 | H2 |
| A3 | D3 |
| F3 | F3 |
| A4 | D4 |
| F4 | H4 |

Answer (score 0):

A more simple example and without recursive:

```
Select main.Azbuka, main.Def from (
    Select 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC))*2 AS RNum, 
        Azbuka, 
        Def 
    from TEST_DB.dbo.table1
    union all 
    Select 
        ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC))*2 + 1) AS RNum, 
        Azbuka, 
        Def 
    from TEST_DB.dbo.table2
) main 
order by main.RNum
```